# Adding POP3/SMTP to iPod 8.1

Tags: email, imap, smtp, ipod

My daughter was using my old iPod Version 6.1.3/Model MC54LL/A, and Santa just brought her her own iPod Version 8.1/ModelPD717LL/A.

I had her email going to my old iPod.  It is going through my own server which is a POP3 server type with POP3 incoming on port 110 and SMTP outgoing on port 25 or port 2525 (with SMTP-AUTH outgoing server authentication).

I added the email account settings to the new iPod, but it shows up as an IMAP account.

How do I change the settings to old school POP instead of IMAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the account and you select the 'Other' option for the account type, at the top is a switch for IMAP and POP3. By default it is IMAP - you just need to change it to POP3.

Comment: Yes, I did select "Other", but there was no option to change from IMAP to POP3.  Don't know whether this is a credible source, but http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596522124/Touch_Mail.pdf states "Apple’s software attempts to figure out which kind of account you have (POP
or IMAP) by the email address. If it can’t make that determination, you arrive
at a second screen now, where you’re asked for such juicy details as the Host
Name for Incoming and Outgoing Mail servers. (This is also where you tap
either
IMAP
or
POP
, to tell the iPod what sort of account it’s dealing with.)

Comment: Now I see.  If you already created an account, you can't change it.  I deleted the old one, and now see what I missed.  I originally had a typo in the email, and it never showed the option to change server type.  Thank you